# FOSUserBundle Unique validator in controller

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to use the FOSUserBundle Unique validator in the controller. As I defined in my `validation.xml` I can choose what property of my entity should be validated:

```
<constraint name="FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique">
   <option name="property">dni</option>
   <option name="message">The value for DNI is already registered</option>
   <option name="groups">
      <value>AppRegistration</value>
      <value>Profile</value>
      <value>UpdateOldUsers</value>
   </option>
</constraint>
```

But when I call it on the controller (following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validating-values-and-arrays)):

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique;

public function acceptNewTosAction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $uniqueConstraint = new Unique(array('property' => 'dni'));
        $formData = $request->request->get('old_user');
        $dni = $formData['dni'];
        $uniqueError = $this->get('validator')->validateValue($dni, $uniqueConstraint);
```

I get this error:
`Expected argument of type FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface, string given`

Is possible to proceed in that way? How I should implement Unique validator in the controller?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized how this should be. Just tell the form in what validation group is:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'Capsa\Bundle\ClubCommonBundle\Entity\User',
        'validation_groups' => array('UpdateOldUsers')

    );
}
```

And then in the controller, check `if ($form->isValid())`